# MapReduce Program in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce, mapper

I have the following Mapper

```
private Text sentiment = new Text();

public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter)
        throws IOException {

    String allPages = value.toString();
    String[] tokens = allPages.split(":::");

    for(int i=0;i<(tokens.length-1);i++)
    {
        String articleID="";
        sentiment.set(tokens[i].trim());
        articleID = tokens[0].trim();
        System.out.println("articleID "+articleID);
        Text articleIDValue = new Text(articleID); 
        output.collect(sentiment,articleIDValue);
    }
    String line = "";
    for(int j=1;j<tokens.length;j++){
        line = line + " "+tokens[j];
        System.out.println("line.... "+line);
    }
    Text lineText = new Text(line.trim());
    output.collect(new Text(tokens[0]),lineText);

}
```

Sample Input:    abc ::: In a market that's awash in tech IPOs, this one is different.
should store keyValue pair as (abc,In a market that's awash in tech IPOs, this one is different.)

Right now this stores as (abc,abc).. **Where am I going wrong?**

Comment: Is it that you have multiple values for one single key ? Why do you do  output.collect(sentiment,articleIDValue); for token[0] ? Can you give some 2-3 sample input output lines?

Comment: YA I realised my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're seeing the result of the first collect() call in which both key and value are set from tokens[0] ("abc").

Comment: Ya. I just re checked. I am collecting it in `output.collect(sentiment,articleIDValue);` .. Thankss